# Q: How to interpret "COGNAC_ERROR" from juju deployment in GCE

Tags: juju, google

I'm trying to get JuJu to deploy openstack on nine virtual nodes in Google Compute Engine.   On the 9th node, I get an error in GCE; it doesn't seem to care what type of service is being deployed.  It seems to be bailing out in instance creation, because it never shows up on the console.   Looking in the GCE logs, I have the following error:

```
version: "1.1" 
trace_id: "operation-1432061995490-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx"
event_timestamp_us: 1432061998942884
event_type: "GCE_OPERATION_DONE"
event_subtype: "compute.instances.insert"
resource { 
  type: "instance"
  name: "juju-xx-xxx-xx-xxxxx-xxxxx-machine-9" 
  id: "0" zone: "us-central1-a"
}
actor {
  user: "988883055924-88888888888888@developer.gserviceaccount.com" 
}
operation {
   type: "operation"
   name: "operation-1432061995490-7777777777777-4f8887cc-e3c375ba"
   id: "2830510622216673609" 
   zone: "us-central1-a"
}
error { code: "COGNAC_ERROR" location: "" detail_message: "" }
```

Through testing, I know the project can have more instances if I create them in the console, so it's not a GCE limitation.   I also know that if I delete one instance I can replace it with another, so it's not the the number created, it's the number running.

So - any idea what a "COGNAC_ERROR" is?   It's repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

It's the error you get when you reach your per region resource limits for a GCE account.  You can request more instances, cores, disks from GCE support, the process is usually quite quick.

[Resource Quotas | Compute Engine Documentation | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please edit your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material..